# Is there scat (as in 'scp', etc) or something similar?

Tags: ssh, cat

I was wondering if there's such a tool to view a text file on a remote server?

Something like `scat user@my.server.com/text.txt`?

Obviously `scat` is just my imagination. But you get the idea! :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ssh user@my.server.com 'cat /text.txt'

Comment: Works great! Thanks. By the way, so if I wanna execute any command, I could just wrap them in a pair of single quotes and put them after the ssh ?

Comment: @OneTwoThree: it's more like "eval": concatenates all the remaining args (separating them with spaces) and interpretes in the shell on the remote side.

Answer (score 2):

Use SSH, e.g. ssh user@host "cat ~/text.test"